# GCP is charging fees for GKE Cluster Management fees

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When we check GCP calculator, GKE cluster management fees is 0. But when running the clusters I'm  being charged about $2.33 every day for GKE cluster management fees...

I wonder if I made a mistake when creating GKE cluster.  Any explanation?

I created the cluster with `location   = "us-west1-a"` which means its zonal. But I'm still being charged.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with GCP support. Yes its free every month even after free trail ends but they only start giving $74 free credit only after you upgrade your account to paid account.

As for the existing $300 free credit, kubernetes Engine charges will get deducted and in the report it'll show under discount (which is for paid account).

So technically $300 free credits include kubernetes engine charges but paid account users get $74 free credit every month for K8s cluster.